# Apples RealityKit Framework in Xamarin.iOS - LiDar scanning

Tags: swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, realitykit, lidar

Okay, I am a Xamarin developer and have been doing some R+D on how I can get a LiDar scanning module up an running for my latest project. In my research I have found Plenty of Swift related projects that I can use in creating a solution, but they all require for me to have RealityKit, a framework currently exclusive to Swift. The only blocker I have is getting this RealityKit into Xamarin C#, Anybody have any ideas on how or any links that I can follow to get this sorted.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Doesn't seem like Microsoft has added bindings for RealityKit: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/tree/main/src You can perhaps ask in there what the plan is to support it. There is an old thread here without much reponse: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6239